# Android save Bitmap to local storage, then compare it with the same bitmap fails

Tags: android, kotlin, bitmap

I have a bitmap and I save it using my emulator to the local storage, where can get the PNG file and put it in my **drawable** folder. After that I generate bitmap from the drawable folder using the **BitmapFactory** and compare it with the original bitmap that was previously saved, using the method **sameAs()** presented in the Bitmap class. But the comparison fails, obviously the problem is when the pixel data for the two bitmaps are compared. My question is how can I save/open the bitmap while keeping the original pixel data without any data loss?

Here is the code to save the Bitmap to the local storage of the emulator:

```
    /**
     * Request the permission from the user to allow witting in the external storage
     * of the device.
     */
    fun requestPermission() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (checkSelfPermission(WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                val permissions = arrayOf(WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                val permissionRequestCode = 1
                requestPermissions(permissions, permissionRequestCode)
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Save the bitmap to local storage on the phone with given folder location and file name
     * @param bitmap bitmap that will be save to the local storage of the phone
     * @param folderName name of the folder where the file will be located
     * @param fileName name of the file that will be in PNG file format
     * @param fileFormat file format of the image 0=png, 1=jpeg
     * @param imageQuality quality of the image only for Jpeg
     */
    fun saveBitmapToLocalStorage(bitmap: Bitmap, folderName: String = "Screenshots", fileName: String = "test", fileFormat: Int = 0, imageQuality: Int = 100) {

        val fileFormatString = arrayListOf("png", "jpg")

        try {
            val imageFile: File
            val dir = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), folderName)
            var success = true
            if (!dir.exists()) {
                success = dir.mkdirs()
            }
            if (success) {
                val date = Date()
                imageFile = File(dir.absolutePath + File.separator + Timestamp(date.time).toString() + "$fileName.${fileFormatString[fileFormat]}")
                imageFile.createNewFile()
            } else {
                return
            }

            val byteArrayOutputStream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
            if (fileFormat == 0) {
                bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, imageQuality, byteArrayOutputStream)
            } else {
                bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, imageQuality, byteArrayOutputStream)
            }

            val fileOutputStream = FileOutputStream(imageFile)
            fileOutputStream.write(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray())
            fileOutputStream.close()

            val values = ContentValues()
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/${fileFormatString[fileFormat]}")
            values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, imageFile.absolutePath)

        } catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
```

First we need to call the method requestPermission() in order for the user to allow permission of writing in the external storage. The following two permissions are also required in the manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I use the *PNG file format to save my image, since I suppose there is no pixel data loss and it supports alpha channel or am I mistaken?

After I have saved my bitmap as PNG to the local storage of the emulator I then extract the files to my PC using the Android Studio with the **Device File Explorer" in the following location **storage->self->primary->Screenshots**.

After I retrieve the PNG file I add it to the **drawable** folder in my res folder, after I generate bitmap using the BitmapFactory:

```
val drawableBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.resources, R.drawable.simple_image)
```

Then I compare the two bitmaps using the method **sameAs()** presented in the Bitmap class

```
drawableBitmap.sameAs(originalBitmap) // false
```

Here the method returns **False**. The reason I want to compare the two bitmaps is for Instrumented Unit Test that checks if a bitmap reproduced generated from a certain method matches the expected one.

Comment: You're mistaken. PNG files are lossy so will always change the data. Your options are: 
1. Don't compare
2. Extract the code that saves to file, and in your tests, don't save them.

Comment: Thanks, I have saved the bitmap pixel data in the "raw" folder and then I read the files with the pixel data from there using the resource Id.

Comment: Be careful that the pixel data isn't too large. It's quite easy for bitmaps to be 50MB+. You shouldn't sacrifice user's storage space just to run your tests

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I have taken in consideration the size of the bitmap and the total size of the pixel data is less than <500KB.

Comment: Do away with the intermediate ByteArrayOutputStream. You can compress your bitmap directly to the FileOutputStream.